# SPlist.AddItem() add only the last item

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm trying to add a couple items of from an XML file to a SharePoint list. Unfortunately, only the last item gets added. Please, show me where am I going wrong.

```
  private void UploadExcelFileToSharePointList()
    {

        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string Url = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;

            using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite(Url))
            {
                using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;


                    SPList Termeslist = spWeb.Lists.GetList(new Guid(ConstVariables2.Termes2Guid), true);

                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(FileUpload1.FileBytes))
                    {

                        XElement xelement = XElement.Load(ms);

                        IEnumerable<XElement> elements = xelement.Elements("text");

                        Console.WriteLine(elements.Count());

                        if (elements.Descendants("body") != null && elements.Descendants("body").Descendants("termEntry") != null)
                        {
                            var elemtermEntries = elements.Descendants("body").Descendants("termEntry");
                            Console.WriteLine(elemtermEntries.Count());

                            int count = elemtermEntries.Count();

                            foreach (XElement xEle in elemtermEntries)
                            {
                                SPListItem itemm = Termeslist.AddItem();

                                var id = xEle.Attribute("id").Value;

                                itemm[ConstVariables2.Terme_Terme_Id_encodé] = id;

                                itemm.Update();
                                Termeslist.Update();

                            }
                        }

                    }

                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you try to debug this? Does the for loop iterate twice?

Comment: yeah it iterate on all items

Comment: You don't need to update the list everytime you add an item. That might be the issue.

Comment: Paul is right Put ' Termeslist.Update(); ' out of the foreach loop. This will solve your problem.

Comment: "Termeslist.Update()" is not required when you want to add/update/delete item to list. Its required only when you have changed some list settings or property. can you post you xml schema here which you are using for adding data?

Answer (score -3):

Use this

```
 SPListItem itemm = Termeslist.Items.Add(); 


`itemm.Update();`not needed  


 Termeslist.Update();
```

Instead

```
SPListItem itemm = Termeslist.AddItem();

itemm.Update();
Termeslist.Update();
```

Comment: If you are changing metadata or the properties of the added item you definitely need to update it. List update is not needed at the end. And you should NEVER use SPList.Items.Add() as this will load the whole item collection to the memory. Instead use SPList.AddItem();